# How to setup ngclass change when route change occurs in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute, ng-view

I am trying to add a class on my main `.container` class when the route changes.

My current simple solution involves an `ng-click` on every main menu url (no other urls on the page):

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function( $scope ){

  $scope.setMain = function( value ){ $scope.isMain = value };

}]);
```

Then in my html:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container" ng-class="{'main': isMain}">
  <ul class="main-menu">
    <li><a href="#" ng-click="setMain(true)"></li>
    <li><a href="#/page-1" ng-click="setMain(false)"></li>
    <li><a href="#/page-2" ng-click="setMain(false)"></li>
  </ul>
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

This seems to work ok as long as I need to add any more urls the problem is when a user does not click on any of the links and directly accesses a url he does not get the main class.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: When you say "directly accesses a url", do you mean they type into the address bar, the route programmatically changes, or something else entirely?

Comment: @maf748 Yes, I mean they type it into the address bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a few different options, but I think the easiest for you would be to setup the `$scope.isMain` value on controller initialisation by looking at `$location`. So inside the controller you could have something like:

```
var loc = $location.path();
if(loc === /* some route rule you require */){
    $scope.isMain = true;
}
```

Have a look here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route as the example down the bottom has a few different examples of what sort of data you can access with regards to the route.

Comment: I thought of using the route params but this means I have to load the same controller for every view. Correct me if I'm wrong but if I want to use a separate controller for one of the views I would have to set up some kind of service to share the route.

Comment: Or you could create a parent controller that handles the state based on route, and have separate child controllers.

Comment: Good idea. Is this what you meant by in your answer?

Comment: Yeah. I use common parent controllers all the time.